# Need a complete example for DynamoDB with php

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, database, nosql

I want to write service in php where -

1) DynamoDB will have table t with two columns key and val

2) I will check if some key exists in table t or not.

3) If exist read data .. if don't exist insert new key-value in table t

I was checking some links
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/index.html#m=AmazonDynamoDB/put_item
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/quick-start.html

Which one to follow ?

Also can someone give me quick example and exact syntax.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to show some work, and ask about a specific problem. This question is the same as 'Write my code for me', which I might do if you met my day rate!

Comment: The first link is old; use the second link. From the [AWS SDK for PHP user guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/index.html), you can find out everything you need to use the AWS SDK, and there are links to the [latest API docs for DynamoDB](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/latest/class-Aws.DynamoDb.DynamoDbClient.html) from there as well.

Comment: This answer may help you
[https://stackoverflow.com/a/74761407/12326605](AWS dynamodb query from php)

Answer (score 55):

The full walkthrough is located [HERE](https://github.com/iSkore/RazrPHP_AWS). It gives you a step by step outline of the setup process for credentials and comes with a easy to use add on to the [PHP SDK for AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/php/)

**AWS Setup**

- AWS doesn't lay out the Credentials setup for you set by step, so I will.

- **1.** Go to AWS and get your **PUBLIC_KEY** and **PRIVATE_KEY**

  - AWS does have tutorials for this [HERE](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html) and [HERE](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html#having-ec2-create-your-key-pair)
- **2.** Open Terminal
- **3.** If you haven't created your credentials yet, in Terminal's fresh page, type in:

  ```
  nano ~/.aws/credentials
  ```

  - The `nano` function page will open up. You will see `GNU nano 2.0.6...` at the top.
- **4.** Inside the `nano` page, type in:

  ```
  [default]
  aws_access_key_id = public_key_ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
  aws_secret_access_key = private_key_s0m3_CR42Y_l3tt3rS_i5y0ur53cr3tK3y
  ```
- **5.** Once you've typed it out, hit **CONTROL + X** (Yes...Control, not Command).
- **6.** Hit **Y** then **ENTER**
- **7.** Get the [AWS_SDK_PHP][4]
- **8.** Go to Your Elastic Beanstalk
- **9.** When you are done creating your app and you see the *Overview* screen with the green check. Look to the side and hit *Configuration*.
- **10.** Under **Software Configuration** -> **Document root:** type in: **/**
- **11.** Under **Property Name** -> **AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID** type in: **[your_access_key]**
- **12.** Under **AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID** is the **AWS_SECRET_KEY**, type in: **[your_secret_key]**
- **13.** When your PHP Project is ready. Put all your files into one folder. Name the folder **[whatever]**, then compress the files inside **[whatever]**. Do not compress the whole folder. Only compress the files in the folder. If one of these files includes your **index.php** or **index.html**, your project will show up on EBS default URL.
- **14.** Your project should be called *Archive.zip* (Mac). Go to EBS, upload the zip and there you go! All finished with AWS Setup!

**AWS Setup**

- **1.**  Put the [AWS_SDK_PHP](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/releases) in an empty folder
- **2.**  At the top of the file using the SDK (`index.php` or whatever), put in:

  ```
  require 'aws/aws-autoloader.php';
  date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');

  use Aws\DynamoDb\DynamoDbClient;

  $client = new DynamoDbClient([
      'profile' => 'default',
      'region'  => 'us-east-1',
      'version' => 'latest'
  ]);
  ```

- **Data Types**

  - **S** = String
  - **N** = Number
  - **B** = Binary

- **The Basic Methods**

  - **Describe Table**

    ```
    $result = $client->describeTable(array(
        'TableName' => '[Table_Name]'
    ));

    echo $result;
    ```
  - **Put Item**

    ```
    $response = $client->putItem(array(
        'TableName' => '[Table_Name]', 
        'Item' => array(
            '[Hash_Name]'   => array('S' => '[Hash_Value]'),
            '[Range_Name]'  => array('S' => '[Range_Value]')
        )
    ));

    //Echoing the response is only good to check if it was successful. Status: 200 = Success
    echo $response;
    ```
  - **Get Item**

    ```
    $response = $client->getItem(array(
        'TableName' => '[Table_Name]',
        'Key' => array(
            '[Hash_Name]'  => array('S' => '[Hash_Value]'),
            '[Range_Name]' => array('S' => '[Range_Value]')
        )
    ));

    echo $response;
    ```
  - **Delete Item**

    ```
    $response = $client->deleteItem(array(
        'TableName' => '[Table_Name]',
        'Key' => array(
            '[Hash_Name]'  => array('S' => '[Hash_Value]'),
            '[Range_Name]' => array('S' => '[Range_Value]')
        )
    ));
    //Echoing the response is only good to check if it was successful. Status: 200 = Success
    echo $response;
    ```
  - **Query Item**

    ```
    $response = $client->query(array(
        'TableName' => '[Table_Name]',
        'KeyConditionExpression' => '[Hash_Name] = :v_hash and [Range_Name] = :v_range',
        'ExpressionAttributeValues' =>  array (
            ':v_hash'  => array('S' => '[Hash_Value]'),
            ':v_range' => array('S' => '[Range_Value]')
        )
    ));

    echo $response;
    ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: could you please add scan example?

Comment: Is there n example on how to insert a SET of values for example (1,2,3,4)

Comment: If only AWS' docs were this simple and concise -thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can Follow Example :
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSILowLevelPHP.Example.html

or you can also follow the guidelines :

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/latest/class-Aws.DynamoDb.DynamoDbClient.html

It hepled me alot

Answer (score 1):

There is now a complete tutorial for DynamoDB with php on AWS website which guides you through creating tables, creating/reading/updating/deleting items, all in php: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.PHP.html