# problems querying by hash and range dynamodb

Tags: php, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

I have a dynamodb table with uid for the hash key and Score for the range key and I am trying to get an element to return.  Unfortunately after going through all of the online documentation I could find I am still getting the same error:

> AWS Error Message: Either the KeyConditions or KeyConditionExpression
>   parameter must be specified in the request.

```
$result = $this->client->query(array(
    'TableName' => 'Leaderboard',
    'KeyConditionExpression' => 'uid = :u_id and Score >= :u_score',
    'ExpressionAttributeValues' =>  array (
        ':u_id' => array('S' => 'test'),
        ':u_score' => array('S' => '100')
    ),
    'ConsistentRead' => true
));

print_r($result['Items']);
```

'KeyConditionExpression' is obviously included within the query parameters.
I also tried 'N' => '100' which makes more sense but that did not fix the error which is seemingly unrelated.

Comment: Can you check if your php-sdk is up to date..

Comment: Thank you that seemed to fix the previous issue :)

Answer (score 0):

- **Query Item**

  ```
  $response = $client->query(array(
      'TableName' => '[Table_Name]',
      'KeyConditionExpression' => '[Hash_Name] = :v_hash and [Range_Name] = :v_range',
      'ExpressionAttributeValues' =>  array (
          ':v_hash'  => array('S' => '[Hash_Value]'),
          ':v_range' => array('S' => '[Range_Value]')
      )
  ));

  echo $response;
  ```

---

Links to help

- **[Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25806267/need-a-complete-example-for-dynamodb-with-php/30701842#30701842)**
- [AWS SDK for PHP](http://aws.amazon.com/php/)
- [A good getting started guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/service-dynamodb.html)
- [SDK Release Page](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/releases)
- [Latest Release (07-23-15)](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/releases/download/3.2.1/aws.zip)
- [DynamoDB Documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/)
- Full documentation for [- RazrPHP -](https://github.com/iSkore/RazrPHP_AWS) is on the GitHub page.

Hope this helps

[amazon-dynamodb](/questions/tagged/amazon-dynamodb) [php](/questions/tagged/php) [query](/questions/tagged/query)