# Installation set up of dynamoDb in PHP

Tags: aws-php-sdk

I have downloaded Libraries from Aws server to install in my server.
I downloaded library from Link - href="http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/download/aws.zip". I want to know how to work this library as using PHP. I have read the document but did not get it working.
please let me know what I need do to make it working, new file need create and configuration etc.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to start using DynamoDB would be to follow a complete step by step guide and then customize the solution as per your need.

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30701842/7328096) to follow a step by step guide.

If you are aware of the basics then you can start creating your own application.