# AWS dynamodb query from php

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a react application and i'm trying to use aws dynamodb, i installed the php sdk but i don't know how to query my db.

I copied the tutorial [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/it_it/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.PHP.html) and i changed the endpoint to: "https://dynamodb.us-west-2.amazonaws.com".

I get this error: {"__type":"com.amazon.coral.service#UnrecognizedClientException","message":"The security token included in the request is invalid."}. I guess i have to add a security token somewhere, i don't know where and neither where to find it.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Could be due to misconfigured your OS system time. Can you verify that your time is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your error, i think you need to check your aws secret key and access key. You can try to install aws cli then create user access programmatically from aws console from this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SettingUp.DynamoWebService.html)

Then you can try your source code after that.

Comment: it worked, thanks! but still get this error {"__type":"com.amazon.coral.service#InvalidSignatureException","message":"'Host' or ':authority' must be a 'SignedHeader' in the AWS Authorization."}

Comment: How do you query to dynamodb? maybe you can paste your code?

Comment: I copied this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/it_it/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.PHP.04.html. and i changed the table name ecc

Answer (score 0):

The following code example shows how to get an item from a DynamoDB table.

```
// '/path/to/aws-autoloader.php' to import AWS SDKs.
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Aws\DynamoDb\DynamoDbClient;
use Aws\Exception\AwsException;
use Aws\DynamoDb\Exception\DynamoDbException;

// Create an SDK class used to share configuration across clients.
$sdk = new Aws\Sdk([
    'region'   => 'us-west-2',
    'version'  => 'latest'
]);

// Use an Aws\Sdk class to create the dynamoDbClient object.
$dynamoDbClient = $sdk->createDynamoDb();

try {
    $dynamoDbClient->getItem([
                'Key'       => [
                    'id' => [
                        'N' => 1,
                    ],
                ],
                'TableName' => 'products',
            ]);
} catch (DynamoDbException $e) {
    // Catch a DynamoDb-specific exception.
    echo $e->getMessage();
} catch (AwsException $e) {
    // This catches the more generic AwsException. You can grab information
    // from the exception using methods of the exception object.
    echo $e->getAwsRequestId() . "\n";
    echo $e->getAwsErrorType() . "\n";
    echo $e->getAwsErrorCode() . "\n";

    // This dumps any modeled response data, if supported by the service
    // Specific members can be accessed directly (e.g. $e['MemberName'])
    var_dump($e->toArray());
}
```

Notice that we did not explicitly provide credentials to the client. That’s because the SDK should detect the credentials from environment variables (via `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`), an AWS credentials INI file in your `HOME` directory, AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) instance profile credentials, or credential providers.
If we don’t provide a credentials option, the SDK attempts to load credentials from your environment in the following order:

1. Load credentials from [environment variables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/guide_credentials_environment.html).
2. Load credentials from [a credentials .ini file](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/guide_credentials_profiles.html).
3. Load credentials from [IAM role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/guide_credentials_assume_role.html).

We can also directly create the service-specific client object like below:

```
$dynamoDbClient = new DynamoDbClient(
        [
            'region'  => 'us-west-2',
            'version' => 'latest',
        ]
```

But AWS highly recommended that you use the Sdk class to create clients if you’re using multiple client instances in your application. As per AWS docs:-

> The `Sdk` class automatically uses the same HTTP client for each `SDK`
> client, allowing SDK clients for different services to perform
> nonblocking HTTP requests. If the `SDK` clients don’t use the same
> HTTP client, then HTTP requests sent by the SDK client might block
> promise orchestration between services.

You can refer to the AWS document pages:-

1. [AWS SDK PHP - BASIC USAGE](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/getting-started_basic-usage.html)
2. [AWS SDK PHP - DynamoDB Examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/php_dynamodb_code_examples.html)
3. [AWS SDK PHP - Configuration guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/guide_configuration.html)
4. [AWS SDK PHP - APIs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-dynamodb-2012-08-10.html#getitem)

I hope this helps.